# Exporting into image file in VIsual Basic

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio

I have about 36 PictureBoxes which together form a 6x6 grid. Is there a way natively or by using something else to convert those images into one bmp which would be 6x6 pixels in width and height.

If you need any more info tell me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this Visual Studio, which you can use to code in C#, VB.NET, F# and others? Or is this VBA, which AFAIK you can't code in Visual Studio, but must use the VB IDE availble in Office programs and others? Please retag appropriately.

Comment: Oh sorry, I accidentaly typed Visual Basic and it somehow took vba for a tag... I'm talking about Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Basic. I'm sorry, again!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new image object that has the dimensions of all the little ones combined (`ImageBox.Image` as far as I remember), then place them inside the image object.